# Can I use a 15 A, 125 VAC switch to replace a 16 A, 125 VAC 1/4 HP rocker switch in my electric fireplace?

Tags: switches

[image]

Old switch:

```
16A 125 VAC 1/4 HP
16A 250 VAC 1/4 HP
```

New switch:

```
15A 125 VAC 1/2 HP  
    250 VAC 1 HP
```

Comment: What does the nameplate on the electric fireplace say? A well-cropped sharp photo would be preferred.

Comment: Do you mean the brand?

Comment: There should be a nameplate (typically near where the power enters the unit in the back or side, out of casual sight) that indicates the voltage and current or power ratings. Like [this](https://i.imgur.com/SgKwuDy.png) one from a supplier on Alibaba.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I have added S's to my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ratings are adequate for the job. 1500W @ 120VAC = 12.5A. Electric Fireplace load will be almost entirely resistive so we don't need to worry about HP rating.

Assuming it fits safely and has similar connections and function it should be okay.

Comment: Got it in. Working great! Thank you for all the help!  -26c feels like -32c with the windchill. Couldn't be happier at the moment.

Comment: Regina? A balmy -1 C here in the GTA. Thanks for the feedback, it’s always helpful to close the loop.

Comment: BC, we're getting it this week. Hopefully the weatherman knows what he's talking about...supposed to warm up in a few days. Fingers  Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 4):

Probably.

If the new switch is a reputable brand and is genuine then it will probably be acceptable. It's specification looks to be entirely adequate for the task.

**Update**: Switch = Techspan 35-688

[**specification sheet**](https://ecat.eleknet.com/PIM_Docs/Docs/STEP_ASSETS_PDF/13242018.pdf) for a Techspan 35-688

Providing the manufacturer is reputable, the switch is suitable.

Your heater is rated at 1500 W 120 VAC.
Current = Watts/Volts = 1500/120 = 12.5A.
(Even at 110 VAC ifr the wttage was still 1500 W (which it wont be)
I = Power / Volts = 1500 / 110 = 13.7 ~= 14A.)

[image]

---

This may be useful.
Short switch replacement video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=orJB96MLbz8)

Comment: It is Techspan 35-688

Comment: Looks like everyone is out trying to sell the [2-part lighted rocker switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfcEX.png) for that REG28 at like $40 each. I then found someone selling the entire fireplace, including the switch, new for $150 canadian! I can see why someone might want to find a different way. Though from what I see right now, the Techspan will only replace one of the two side-by-side switches.

Comment: Mine has a power switch if I just want the flames, and the double switch for high/low heat settings. I went to five electrical shops before I finally found the Techspan switch.Other places had switches but wouldn't fit. Cost me $16.00 canadian. Works great!

Comment: @Pamela The fact that your switch has failed, and that there is a thriving market for vastly overpriced replacement switches, suggests that the original switch did not meet its claimed specification. The Techspan switch is unlikely to be worse.